# How to get the first cell that has a value in phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

I have an excel file that have first data in cell B4, this is the first of the content area. The content area range is B4:D9.

How can I get the B4?

I used this code but it is not getting the b4,

```
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
$data = array();
$highestNum = 0;
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    $data[] = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                    "",
                                    TRUE,
                                    FALSE);
    $columns[] = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($row-1);
    $highestNum = $row;
}
```

Comment: `'A' . $row` Perhaps by changing `'A'` to `'B'` and by setting the value of $row to 4

Comment: Or, if you only want that one cell, then perhaps using the methods described in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#retrieving-a-cell-value-by-coordinate)... We write docs so that you don't have to ask basic questions like this on SO